# Route specific IPs to secondary ethernet network inside Virtual Machine

Tags: networking, virtualbox, network-manager, netplan

I have a Ubuntu 20.04 VM running on a Windows 10 machine. The Windows machine is connected to the company I work for via a VPN.

On the VM configuration I created 2 networks, one using NAT mode and other Bridged mode.

The NAT network inside the VM uses the VPN from the Windows machine.
The Bridged network inside the VM goes directly to my router.

I would like to configure my network so that only some IPs should use the NAT connection and all other go to the Bridge connection.

I've created this entry on `/etc/hosts`

```
10.333.44.10    github.company.com
```

and a NetPlan config:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp0s8: #Bridge
      gateway4: 192.168.15.1
      dhcp4: yes
    enp0s3: #NAT
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [10.0.2.0/24]
      routes:
        - to: 10.0.0.0/24
          via: 10.0.2.0
          metric: 10
```

When I have no NetPlan configured, ifconfig gives me:

```
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
```

I can access everything on the internet without any problems, but if I try to access https://github.company.com I get timeout error.

I would like to make that every host that uses `10.\*.\*.\*` to be routed to `enp0s3` network.

If I disable the default Bridge network and use only the default NAT network I'm able to access the github url without any problems.

I've never messed with routing, so I have no idea what I am doing.

Comment: `to:` should be `10.333.44.0/24` and `via` should state the gateway at `10.0.2.0` (it is `10.0.2.2` in most cases when using virtualbox)

Comment: Read `man ip-route ip`. It's easy to route `10.*.*.*` packets to `enp0s3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, PEdroArthur comment was what I needed to make this work.

I'll put the correct configuration below if someone has the same question.

This configuration should makes everything different from the IPs on `enp0s3` (NAT) route list go via `enp0s8` (Bridge).

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp0s8: #Bridge
      gateway4: 192.168.15.1
      dhcp4: yes
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 192.168.15.1
          metric: 11      
    enp0s3: #NAT
      dhcp4: false 
      addresses: [10.0.2.0/24]
      routes:
        - to: 10.333.44.0/24
          via: 10.0.2.2
          metric: 10
        - to: XXX.XXX.XXX.0/24
          via: 10.0.2.2
          metric: 10
```

Just change the `XXX.XXX.XXX` for the IP you need. You can add as many as needed.

Create a new `config.yaml` on `/etc/netplan` and run `netplan try` to try the new configuration for 2 minutes and `netplan apply` to make it permanent.